# Cannot Connection to Port at Simple Node Js server

Tags: node.js

I am stumped.

I have a node js server running on a subdomain.

Every time i try to access it from a browser i get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

Here is my server code

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer( function (request, response){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124, "my-server-ip");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Additional  Information:
I am running a VPS with Hostgator. 
The subdomain shares an IP with main domain; something like 412.x.xx.xxx .

Comment: And no errors in the console, like `createServer is deprecated` or something ?

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is using that port?

Comment: No error message in console.

Comment: Nothing else running on that port

Answer (score 0):

insert console log inside create server function. Then you can identify error for this. Also you can use error response.

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer( function (request, response){

  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');

}).listen(8124, "my-server-ip");
```

Comment: Seems like i cannot reach the server at all. The browser keeps returning Connection Refused error. Also i used console.log as suggested - nothing showed up.